# In Pysimplegui, I want to display a window that does not wait for an event

Tags: pysimplegui

Using PysimpleGUI, I want to update an image in window 2 when I click a button in window 1. I do not want to interact with window 2, just display it, then display a new image on next button click in window 1. At the moment, the code forces me to close window 2 before the button in window 1 will display a new image.

Can PysimpleGUI display a window as (in effect) output only? Any help gratefully received! For info, all .png images have the same dimensions, if that helps.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme("DarkAmber")

count = 0
# Image set
img_set = ["00.png",
           "01.png",
           "02.png",
           "03.png",
           "04.png",
           "05.png",
           "06.png",
           "07.png",
           "08.png",
           "09.png",
           "10.png"]

# Display windows
while (count < 11):
    # Layout for Buttons
    lay1 = [
        [sg.RButton("OK"), sg.Button("Cancel")]
        ]
    win1 = sg.Window("Count", lay1, location = (500, 600))
    event, values = win1.read() #close = True)
    if event == "Cancel" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "OK":
        if count > 0:
            win2.close()

        # Layout for Images
        lay2 = [
            [sg.Image(img_set[count])]
            ]
        win2 = sg.Window("Image", lay2, location = (700, 600), modal = False)
        event, values = win2.read(close = True)
        count += 1
        print(count)

win1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can finalize both two windows with option `finalize=True` before you read any event in event loop.

Following code just show how to show both of windows and how it handle the events from main window and update the image in another window.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import PySimpleGUI as sg

""" Create 10 Images for the execution of this script
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 80)
for i in range(10):
    im = Image.new("RGBA", (320, 240), "blue")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im, mode='RGBA')
    draw.text((160, 120), f'{i:0>2d}.png', font=font, anchor='mm', align='center')
    im.save(f'{i:0>2d}.png')
"""

image_set = [f'{i:0>2d}.png' for i in range(10)]

sg.set_options(dpi_awareness=True)  # For WINDOWS, maybe not necessary

layout2 = [[sg.Image(filename=image_set[0], size=(320, 240), key='-IMAGE-')]]
window2 = sg.Window("Image", layout2, finalize=True, no_titlebar=True)
x, y = window2.current_location()

layout1 = [[sg.RButton("OK"), sg.Button("Cancel")]]
window1 = sg.Window("Count", layout1, location=(x-200, y), finalize=True)

index = 0
while True:

    event, values = window1.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
        break
    elif event == 'OK':
        index = (index + 1) % 10
        window2['-IMAGE-'].update(filename=image_set[index])

window2.close()
window1.close()
```

If nothing more, you can put them into only one window if possible.

Comment: Many thanks, Jason - especially for the worked example. I was starting tear out my remaining hair! You, sir, are a star. (And I was starting to contemplate putting everything in one window, but your solution fits the bill perfectly.)

Comment: Also, I didn't know about the "no_titlebar" option, which is an added bonus.